# Remove previously stored cookies from Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Is there a method or any other way which I can you use to delete all previously stored cookies in Mechanize? It remembers that I'm logged in which in my case is not a good thing. I should need to log in everytime I connect to the page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After something like

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get SOMEURL
```

you can remove all cookies with `agent.cookie_jar.clear!`, so the next request of the agent will not send any cookies.

Comment: You saved my day. Excellect answer!